# How to retain data (i.e color) on refresh or login of another user?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am new to php.. I have made a page where a user can login in & book a room for meeting. I used tables to display the time slot. On click of a time slot a form appears & where user inputs the details. On click of submit the data is inserted into db .But if the page is refreshed the color in the table disappears or if any other user logins in the color is not present.

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head><title>MRA</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
.name-error,
.meeting-error
{
    color: red;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

#plan 
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -239px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#plan-bg 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 5;
}
.close 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.close:hover 
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#datepicker 
{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.calender-date 
{
    padding: 0 10px;
}

#time-slot-msg,
#alert-msg 
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -184.5px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#time-slot-msg p,
#alert-msg p { font-weight: bold; }

#time-slot-msg .close,
#alert-msg .close 
{ 
    font-size: 15px;
    right: 20px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $index;
    $('.meeting-error').hide();
    $(".meeting-timetable tr > td + td").click(function(e) {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('The selected time slot has already been assigned');
        } else {
            var $thisVal = $(this).prevAll('td:first-child').text();
            $index = $(this).index();
            // Start time.
            $(".start-time option").each(function() {
                if (($(this).text() === $thisVal)) {
                    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    $(this).prevAll().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });
            // Change end time.
            $(".end-time option").each(function() {
                if (($(this).text() === $thisVal)) {
                    $(this).next().attr('selected', 'selected');
                    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(this).prevAll().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });
            // Date input select.
            var $date = $('.meeting-timetable tr:first-child th').text();
            var dateFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date($date));
            $('.date').val(dateFormat);
            $('#meeting').val('');
            $('.meeting-error').hide();
            // Show dialog box.
            $('#plan, #plan-bg').fadeIn();
        }
    });
    // On submit click change background color.
    $('.submit-button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedValue = $(".start-time option:selected").text(),
        selectedEndValue = $(".end-time option:selected").text(),
        $name = $('input[name=txtname]').val();
        if($('#meeting').val()) {
            $(".meeting-timetable tr > td").each(function()  {
                if ($(this).text() === selectedValue) {
                    $(this).parent('tr').addClass('active');
                    var $active1 = $(this).nextAll().eq($index - 1).css('background-color',  'orange').addClass('active').attr("title", $name);
                }
                if ($(this).text() === selectedEndValue) {
                    $(this).nextAll().eq($index - 1).css('background-color',  'orange').addClass('active').attr("title", $name);
                    var $parent =  $(this).parent('tr').prevUntil('tr.active').addClass('active');
                }
                // Prev all td selected.
                $($parent).each(function(){
                    $(this).children('td').nextAll().eq($index - 1).css('background-color', 'orange').addClass('active').attr("title", $name);
                });
            });
        }
        // Form validation.
        if ($('#meeting').val() === '') {
            $('.meeting-error').fadeIn();
        }
        // Grab form values
        var formData = {
            'txtrname'    : $('input[name=txtrname]').val(),
            'txtname'     : $('input[name=txtname]').val(),
            'txtpurpose'  : $('input[name=txtpurpose]').val(),
            'attendee'    : $('select[name=attendee]').val(),
            'txtdate'     : $('input[name=txtdate]').val(),
            'btime'       : $('select[name=btime]').val(),
            'etime'       : $('select[name=etime]').val()
        };

        if($('#meeting').val().trim()) {
            // Ajax form submit.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert.php",
                data: formData,
                success: function()
                {
                    $('#alert-msg').fadeIn();
                    $('#plan').fadeOut();
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please enter the purpose of meeting');
        }
    });
    // on focus function
    $('#meeting').focus(function() {
        $('.meeting-error').fadeOut();
    }).blur(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $('.meeting-error').fadeIn();
        }
    });
    // Reset button functionality.
    $('.reset-button').click(function() {
        $('.inputDisabled').prop("disabled", false);
        $(".start-time option, .end-time option").removeAttr('disabled',  'disabled');
        $('.start-time option, .end-time option').removeAttr('selected', 'selected');
        $('.end-time option:eq(0)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('.end-time option:eq(1)').attr('selected', 'selected');
        $('.meeting-error').hide();
    });
    $(".close").click(function() {
        $('.pop-up').fadeOut();
    });
    $('.calender-date').html($.datepicker.formatDate('d MM, yy', new Date()));
    // Adding calender.
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
        onSelect: function (date) {
            $('.calender-date').text(date);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#BEBCBC">
<h3 align="right"><a href="#">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php
echo ucwords($_SESSION['usr_name']);
?>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="logout.php">Logout</a></h3>
<table border="1" align="right" width="70%">
<tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><h1>Click to Book a Time Slot</h1></td>   </tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="red" align="center">Booked</td><td align="center" bgcolor="orange">Requested</td><td align="center" bgcolor="Green">Available</td>   </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">| <a href="1today.php"> Today </a> |</td></tr></table>
<table class="meeting-timetable" border="1" align="right" width="70%">
<tr><th colspan="2" class="calender-date" align="center"></th></tr>
<tr><td align="center" width="10%">8:00 a.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">8:30 a.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">9:00 a.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">9:30 a.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">10:00 a.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">10:30 a.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">11:00 a.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">11:30 a.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">12:00 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">12:30 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">1:00 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">1:30 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">2:00 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">2:30 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">3:00 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">3:30 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">4:00 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">4:30 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">5:00 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">5:30 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">6:00 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">6:30 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">7:00 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">7:30 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">8:00 p.m</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<div id="plan" class="pop-up" style="display :none ">
<span class="close">Close</span>
<form align="center" method="post" id="inform">
<h1 align="center">Meeting Details</h1>
<table>
<tr><td><b>Room : </td><td><input type="text" name="txtrname" value="Karma"  readonly></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="txtname" readonly value="    <?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['usr_name']);  ?>"   ></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Purpose of Meeting :</td><td> <input id="meeting" type="text" name="txtpurpose"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>No. of Attendee :</td><td><select name="attendee"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option> </select></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Date :</td><td> <input class="date" type="text" name="txtdate"  readonly value="yyyy/mm/dd"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Time : </td><td>Start Time <select class="start-time" name="btime">
<option value="8:00 a.m">8:00 a.m</option>
<option value="8:30 a.m">8:30 a.m</option>
<option value="9:00 a.m">9:00 a.m</option>
<option value="9:30 a.m">9:30 a.m</option>
<option value="10:00 a.m">10:00 a.m</option>
<option value="10:30 a.m">10:30 a.m</option>
<option value="11:00 a.m">11:00 a.m</option>
<option value="11:30 a.m">11:30 a.m</option>
<option value="12:00 p.m">12:00 p.m</option>
<option value="12:30 p.m">12:30 p.m</option>
<option value="1:00 p.m">1:00 p.m</option>
<option value="1:30 p.m">1:30 p.m</option>
<option value="2:00 p.m">2:00 p.m</option>
<option value="2:30 p.m">2:30 p.m</option>
<option value="3:00 p.m">3:00 p.m</option>
<option value="3:30 p.m">3:30 p.m</option>
<option value="4:00 p.m">4:00 p.m</option>
<option value="4:30 p.m">4:30 p.m</option>
<option value="5:00 p.m">5:00 p.m</option>
<option value="5:30 p.m">5:30 p.m</option>
<option value="6:00 p.m">6:00 p.m</option>
<option value="6:30 p.m">6:30 p.m</option>
<option value="7:00 p.m">7:00 p.m</option>
<option value="7:30 p.m">7:30 p.m</option>
<option value="8:00 p.m" disabled>8:00 p.m</option>
</select>
- End Time <select class="end-time" name="etime">
<option value="8:00 a.m">8:00 a.m</option>
<option value="8:30 a.m">8:30 a.m</option>
<option value="9:00 a.m">9:00 a.m</option>  
<option value="9:30 a.m">9:30 a.m</option>
<option value="10:00 a.m">10:00 a.m</option>
<option value="10:30 a.m">10:30 a.m</option>
<option value="11:00 a.m">11:00 a.m</option>
<option value="11:30 a.m">11:30 a.m</option>
<option value="12:00 p.m">12:00 p.m</option>
<option value="12:30 p.m">12:30 p.m</option>
<option value="1:00 p.m">1:00 p.m</option>
<option value="1:30 p.m">1:30 p.m</option>
<option value="2:00 p.m">2:00 p.m</option>
<option value="2:30 p.m">2:30 p.m</option>
<option value="3:00 p.m">3:00 p.m</option>
<option value="3:30 p.m">3:30 p.m</option>
<option value="4:00 p.m">4:00 p.m</option>
<option value="4:30 p.m">4:30 p.m</option>
<option value="5:00 p.m">5:00 p.m</option>
<option value="5:30 p.m">5:30 p.m</option>
<option value="6:00 p.m">6:00 p.m</option>
<option value="6:30 p.m">6:30 p.m</option>
<option value="7:00 p.m">7:00 p.m</option>
<option value="7:30 p.m">7:30 p.m</option>
<option value="8:00 p.m">8:00 p.m</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td></td>
<td><input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<div id="plan-bg" class="pop-up"></div>
<div id="alert-msg" class="pop-up"><span class="close">Close</span><p>Your  request has been sent to admin.</p></div>
<div id="time-slot-msg" class="pop-up"><span class="close">Close</span>     <p>This time slot is already booked.</p></div>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: either the data is not stored in the db, or your not processing it correctly.

Comment: Data is stored in the db & the selected time slot i.e start time & end time changes to orange color. But if i refresh the page or another user logins in the color disappears.

Comment: refresh is simply a new page load , so either you did something to the data preciously added, or are not processing it correctly.

Comment: If you click on any <td> then a form appears where user fills the data & on click of submit the selected <td> changes to orange & the data is inserted in db correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not looking up the meeting data and adding the 'active' css class to the time-slots that are already booked when you build your table. It is no use storing the data if you do not then use it when required.

That means that you need a query in your code to return the bookings and a loop control to check if each time-slot has been booked. When it has, add the active css class to that td.

`<td class="active">`

So modify your code to retrieve the bookings and ask more questions when you have problems with the new code.

PS instead of adding the background-color directly, define it as the background-color of the active class. Then just adding the class will produce the desired effect.

Comment: Sir i have made few changes and tried. But i'm not able to get desired answer. Please help me with the code.